# create a separate branch along with git cherry-pickup

Tags: git, github

Recently I read about `cherry picking` from this I got that, cherry picking in git means to choose a commit from one branch and apply it onto another.

Now I have to scenario as say I have four commits as A, B ,C and D. Currently I am on commit A and by using `git cherry-pick <hash_of D>` I pick-up changes of commit D.
But when I check the branch it is showing `(no branch)`.

Now I have do such that I can also use cherry-pick and also give the branch name.
How can  I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tree looks like this:

```
A---B---C---D       master
```

If you checked out commit A, then you are currently in detached HEAD state, meaning there is no current branch.  You cherry-picked commit D, but you're still in detached HEAD state:

```
A---B---C---D       master
 \
  D'                (no branch)
```

Here `D'` is your cherry-picked copy of `D`.  All you have to do is create a new branch.

```
git branch my-new-branch
```

Then you will have:

```
A---B---C---D       master
 \
  D'                my-new-branch
```